# Camel HTTP Howto

Tags: http, apache-camel

Anybody can help me understand why this is not working?

```
   <route>
            <from uri="restlet:/foo"/>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpBaseUri">
                        <simple>http://www.google.com</simple>
                    </setHeader>
            <to uri="http://dummyhost"/>
            <to uri="mock:result"/>
</route>
```

My expectation was that by setting CamelHttpBaseUri (Exchange.HTTP_URI), the URL in the endpoint would be ignored and the header used. But this is not happening. What am I missing?

Comment: `Exchange.HTTP_URI` is `CamelHttpUri`, not `CamelHttpBaseUri`, at least in Camel 2.10.X.

Comment: That was my mistake. Would you mind adding your comment as answer so i can accept it?

Comment: You can use Exchange.HTTP_URI as headerName in XML too. Camel will detect this. Then you can use the same constant as in Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exchange.HTTP_URI` is `CamelHttpUri`, not `CamelHttpBaseUri`, at least in Camel 2.10.x.